# All of ESX4 hosts not responding after rebooting vCenter server

Tags: vmware-esx, high-availability, vmware-vcenter

I'm constructing 5ESX+a vCenter serv.
I'm testing FT on the system.

Today vCenter OS (W2008) demanded　system reboot.
After rebooting vCenter Serv. All of ESX hosts have alert icon.
end indicate "not responding"

I tried to connect ESX (version 4) hosts to vCenter again.
Once they came back normally, but after few seconds ,They turned red again.
All of them have ping connection to vCenter serv.

There are no red messages in Tusks and events.
Two messages are found in Summary of Cluster
・There aren't sufficient resource for HA failover.
・Can't contact primary HA agent.

I'm also not able to reset FT configuration because all of VMS aren't accessed from vCenter

What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given you have vSphere AND vCentre - both of which aren't 12 months old yet you MUST have a valid support contract with VMWare (at least for a couple of weeks minimum anyway) - I'd suggest you place a call with them.

It's not that I don't want to help but when you have a production-affecting problem and a valid support contract I'd always recommend people go direct primarily and come to us secondary.